# Installshield: How to update already running windows service

Tags: installshield

I have two setups, both are installing the same windows service, lets say myservice.

My customer installs the setup 1, and some time later she wants to install setup 2. In setup 2, I want to update myservice. Since service is already running, setup 2.exe fails to update.

How can I solve the problem? I tried to define custom action, but custom action is triggered after installshield tries to copy the service files. I also tried the Install Stop option in Components->myservice->Event tab, but it does the same again.

How can I update my service if it is already running?

Answer (score 0):

You can sequence your stop service to occur prior to file deploy. Probably somewhere in the execute sequence. If needed, use deferred mode. This may require the CustomActionData property to avoid hard-coded paths.